# URL Rewriting in core PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite URL of a query string in core PHP

> my querystring is www.myurl.com/category.php?categoryid=$category-id; ?>&language_id=
>
> I need to rewrite this to www.myurl.com/abc if category-id=1  and >www.myurl.com/xyz if category-ID=2
>
> By using the following code in htaccess I could change it to www.myurl.com/category/1/1

my htaccess code is

```
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) category.php?cat_id=$1&lang_id=$2
```

But now I need to change it to 
myurl.com/abc   &   myurl.com/xyz

any help??
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just pass everything then split it up in the app.

Comment: How? Can you explain?

Comment: You just can use a redirect, in example using header()

Comment: I have a category page and fill this category page with the appropriate id